# Full fledged local CGI Server

Tags: python, cgi, localhost

I want to set up a local CGI Server that treats any any `*.py` file as a cgi-script and executes it. But using `CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler` does only execute files contained in the `cgi_directories` attribute.

### How can I achieve that any Python script is executed as cgi-script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace the `CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.is_cgi` function at your own risk:

```
import CGIHTTPServer

def is_cgi(self):
    if self.path.endswith('.py'):
        self.cgi_info = CGIHTTPServer._url_collapse_path_split(self.path)
        return True
    return False

CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.is_cgi = is_cgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html) I think that you're probably looking for this:

> **cgi_directories**
>
> This defaults to ['/cgi-bin', '/htbin'] and describes directories to treat as containing CGI scripts.

Hence, setting `cgi_directories` to whatever you need, you will be able to serve the scripts in a directory that doesn't match any of the previous names.

Alternatively, I'd say you can also at a link to the script in one of the expected directories to add access to that script.